# Import Error: no module named re

Tags: python-3.x

I converted one .py file to .exe using cx_freeze.
I am using python 3.2 and my OS is windows 7
the .py file executes properly in python interpreter and in command line..but..
when i create its exe file and execute it...it gives me following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py",
>   line 2 7, in     exec(code, m.__dict__)   File "HB2.py", line
>   1, in       File "C:\Python32\lib\random.py", line 40, in
>       from warnings import warn as _warn   File
>   "C:\Python32-64\lib\warnings.py", line 6, in    File
>   "C:\Python32-64\lib\linecache.py", line 10, in    File
>   "C:\Python32-64\lib\tokenize.py", line 27, in  ImportError:
>   No module named re

can u please help me in resolving these??

Answer (score 0):

You likely didn't tell cx_freeze to include the re module, which is what is causing the error. If you give us an idea of what your setup script looks like, we can tell you where to tell cx_freeze to include the re module.

Answer (score 0):

To build the exe your code have to be first compiled and then linked. In the Linking step you must say where any external module, library or objectcode is so the linker can correctly integrate them in the executable.